# Change face landmarks using face mesh

Tags: computer-vision, python, image-processing, face-detection

I'm trying to use computer vision or image processing techniques to make nose smaller. Using a SDK called `mediapipe` we are able to get face mesh, which provides points to face landmarks. If we want to make the nose smaller, theoretically we should change the corresponding number. But I don't think that's just the coordinates. I guess we have to transform/warp the actual face texture along with it, not just the coordinates of the number.

Is there any tips how this can be done? Some examples or snippets would be great.

[image]